# SendKeys.SendWait doesn't work in some cases

Tags: c#, console-application, sendkeys

My target is to send keyboard events to external application.
From my application, I'm launching a **C# console application** that bring the target application to the front and uses `SendKeys.SendWait` to send keyboards events. I ran into a rate case where the command doesn't have any affect.

When debugging it, it works but when running it not in debug it fails.
I think it as something to do with the fact that when debugging my application is the active application.

Comment: accept some answers, and people might be more willing to help....

Comment: You are right I wasn't aware of it I just used the useful buttons. But now I accepted all of my questions. Thanks,

Comment: I check it with the spy++ and got the following deference:
 007F02C6 S WM_ACTIVATE fActive:WA_INACTIVE fMinimized:False hwndPrevious:(null)
 007F02C6 S message:0xC3DA [Registered:"SunAwtComponent"] wParam:00000000 lParam:00000000
 007F02C6 R message:0xC3DA [Registered:"SunAwtComponent"] lResult:00000001
 007F02C6 R WM_ACTIVATE

Comment: Visual Basic has the AppActivate call

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# SendKeys.SendWait() doesn't always work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069123/c-sharp-sendkeys-sendwait-doesnt-always-work)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do a little work, and it changes depending on the version of Windows. There's an MSDN page that has a good explanation and an example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link.
I don't understand what should I do I'm using sendWait run with .NET Framework 3.0 and experiencing the problem.

Comment: Read everything on that page from "Simulating Keyboard Input" down. There's a section titled "To send a keystroke to a different application" it shows an example of sending key to another application using sendWait. You need to read it all though, as it points out issues that you might get.

Comment: Like stated in the answer, it also depends upon the version of .NET framework being used. It worked for me on .NET 4.5 but didn't work on .NET 4.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it works for me.

```
var text = "Hello";
var target = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
var routedEvent = TextCompositionManager.TextInputEvent;
target.RaiseEvent( new TextCompositionEventArgs( InputManager.Current.PrimaryKeyboardDevice, 
new TextComposition(InputManager.Current, target, text)) { RoutedEvent = routedEvent });
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1646568

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should run your program as an administrator. At least, it works for me in some cases.