# C# SendKeys.SendWait() doesn't always work

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I am trying to make an application that sends keys to an external application, in this case aerofly FS. I have previously used the `SendKeys.SendWait()` method with success, but this time, it doesn't quite work the way I want it to.

I want to send a `"G"` keystroke to the application and testing it out with Notepad I do get G's. But in aerofly FS nothing is received at all. Pressing `G` on the keyboard does work though.

This is my code handling input data (from an Arduino) an sending the keystrokes,

```cs
private void handleData(string curData)
{
    if (curData == "1")
        SendKeys.SendWait("G");
    else
    { }
}
```

Comment: @phadaphunk you're comment is quite the opposite of what the question is.  The questions asks how to *send* a key to an application automagically, not *retrieve* the key a users types in the application.

Comment: `SendKeys` is a `keypress` event with no `delay` and what you need is `keyup` + `delay` + `keydown` as here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75989913/3057246

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too have run into external applications where SendKeys didn't work for me.

As best I can tell, some applications, like applets inside a browser, expect to receive the key down, followed by a pause, followed by a key up, which I don't think can be done with SendKeys.

I have been using a C# wrapper to the AutoIt Library, and have found it quite easy to use.

Here's a link to quick guide I wrote for [integrating AutoIt into a C# project](http://tonylitchfield.com/getting-started/5-using-autoit-within-c-and-visual-studio-2010.html).

Once you have the wrapper and references, you can send "G" with the following:

```
private void pressG()
{
   AutoItX3Declarations.AU3_Send("{g}");
}
```

or with a pause,

```
private void pressG()
{
   AutoItX3Declarations.AU3_Send("{g down}", 0);
   AutoItX3Declarations.AU3_Sleep( 50 );          //wait 50 milliseconds
   AutoItX3Declarations.AU3_Send("{g up}", 0);
}
```

AutoIt also allows you programmatically control the mouse.

Comment: Although this does work very nicely, aerofly FS still doesn't register any input. When mapping the buttons in aerofly, it does respond on key down, meaning I don't have to release the key for it to respond. However, when using my application it detects nothing.

Comment: Okay, my bad. Apparently I had messed up my code somehow. This works brilliantly, thank you very much!

Comment: There is no need for an external library as there is `p/invoke` plz see my answer for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/75989913/3057246

Answer (score 0):

You can try enclosing `G` as `{G}` and used with `SendKeys` as

```cs
SendKeys.SendWait("{g}");
```

But even that will not work in the game cause it's just a `keypress` not a `keydown` + delay + `keyup` event cycle, so you can try to keep pressing `G` 5 times as

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{g 5}");
```

this will be same as pressing `W` 5 times so in a gaming character will only may move a bit and will not be visible to you. I think that what happened with you and believe me `SendKeys` are not designed for that and have it's own limitations.

---

But there is `windowsApi` function wich can be `p/invoke` in any c# code natively and one of it is `keybd_event`. The following example is doing the same:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

public static void Delay(int delay)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
}

public static void KeyDown(KEYCODE keycode)
{
    keybd_event((byte)keycode, 0x0, 0, 0);// presses ctrl
}

public static void KeyPress(KEYCODE keycode, int delay)
{
    keybd_event((byte)keycode, 0x0, 0, 0);// presses ctrl
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    keybd_event((byte)keycode, 0x0, 2, 0); //releases ctrl
}

public static void KeyUp(KEYCODE keycode)
{
    keybd_event((byte)keycode, 0, 2, 0); //release
}

public static void Type(string message)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(message);
}
```

I have created [Robot.cs](https://gist.github.com/Killercodes/5ff6cdbbb46391fdb0d5ae1e5b504284) to do the Mouse & keyboard automation where you can find the `KEYCODE` for the above example.