# Sendkeys.send send alt+space+n combination

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard-shortcuts, combinations, sendkeys

The title pretty much explains question. I want to sen alt+space+n combination via `Senkeys.send` method, how this could be done? So far I've tried  `SendKeys.Send("% N");` but it's not working.

Comment: Are you trying to add a key trigger? Ex: I press the buttons and something happens? or are you trying to send a key combo to the OS?

Answer (score 0):

Spacebar isn't a traditional modifier key, so I believe you will need to send the keyUp and keyDown events seperately.

I'm not completely familiar with C# sendkeys, since I use the AutoIt library for this kind of thing, with AutoIt the commands would be something like:

```
private void pressAltSpaceN()
{
   AutoItX3Declarations.AU3_Send("{alt down}", 0);
   AutoItX3Declarations.AU3_Send("{space down}", 0);
   AutoItX3Declarations.AU3_Send("{n down}", 0);
   AutoItX3Declarations.AU3_Send("{n up}", 0);
   AutoItX3Declarations.AU3_Send("{space up}", 0);
   AutoItX3Declarations.AU3_Send("{alt up}", 0);
}
```

Hopefully someone else can tell how to send keyUp and keyDown events using SendKeys, otherwise you can learn how to integrate AutoIt into C# using the answer to this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069123/c-sharp-sendkeys-sendwait-doesnt-always-work).

Answer (score 0):

The string you're using should work. Perhaps the default journaling hook doesn't work with the application you're trying to minimize. You could try using the alternate method using app.config and SendInput (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

A better way to solve the problem would be to obtain a handle to the focused window using [GetActiveWindow](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetActiveWindow.html), then call [ShowWindowAsync](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ShowWindowAsync.html) and pass in a [ShowWindowCommand](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/ShowWindowCommand.html) value of 2.

Comment: My string works only without N SendKeys.Send("% "); I am getting a menu with minimize, restore down... options. So it is not applications fault.

Comment: @user2412672 "% n" (or N) works fine for me. When you physically type Alt+Space, does the focused application contain an option for Minimize with the 'n' underlined?

Comment: @user2412672 Try SendKeys.SendWait("% "); SendKeys.SendWait("n");