# How do I simulate Text input to a WPF TextBox?

Tags: .net, wpf, textbox

I want to simulate user input to a WPF TextBox. I want to input a character such that the OnPreviewTextInput event is triggered. I tried setting the Text through the Text property, but this didn't trigger the event:

```
public void SomeFunction()
{
    var textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.Text = "A";                     
}
```

Can I trigger the event explicitly somehow?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See the answer to [How can I programmatically generate keypress events in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c) for a good description of how to simulate input events.

You could also do:

```
TextCompositionManager.StartComposition(
    new TextComposition(InputManager.Current, textBox, "A"));
```

This will raise the PreviewTextInput event and then raise the TextInput event and change the text.

Comment: What about backspace?

Comment: @Jordan: You should just ask that as a new question.  You might be looking for something like `EditingCommands.Backspace.Execute(null, textBox);`, but it's hard to say without more detail.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this would be by using WinAPI, SendMessage to be specific:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

Then call it this way, when the focus is on the TextBox:

```
SendMessage(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, 0x0102, 72, 0)
```

0x0102 is the constant value for WM_CHAR and 72 is the keycode for `H` (you can change this accordingly).

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I find Quartermeisters solution cleaner and simpler.

Comment: Yes, sure! That's why I gave you a +1 :-)

Comment: Nice! One question though: why would this code produce the letter 'H' instead of 'h'?

Comment: And also, for special keys (like ä) it returns a false key for me.