# keyboard press without Hardware press

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

how can I press "Enter" on c# and WPF without pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> on hardware keyboard ?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, so you're saying SendKeys is unavailable?

Check these threads, on the MSDN forums: http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/915cb53a-704b-4047-8fd0-e7c5a8feae5e/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6557c1eb-6eb5-4f4a-84d6-4ae4fb5b9dab/

Sounds like you can trap KeyDown events, but that's not exactly what you want...

**Oh, wait! Check this SO thread: [How can I programmatically generate keypress events in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c)**

Beyond that, *How* and *why* do you need to send "Enter" without a keyboard press? There may be a different solution lurking there. :)

Comment: TO enable to write on autocompletebox because Focus() didn't work it just choose the control but can't enable to write untill I press enter or tab !

Comment: Ok. So you're programmatically Focusing on the autocompletebox, and you want to send an Enter press so that (a) the user can just start typing without having to focus on the field themselves, or (b) you can programmatically "type" in the box? Are you trying to achieve (a) or (b)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're working with WindowsForms... by using `SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");`

See this documentation here as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx

Comment: @salamonti, this important information should have been stated either in your question or tags.

Comment: @salamonti: You didn't say so in your question, no need to act up.