# Programmatically generate keydown presses for WPF unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, unit-testing, wpf-controls

I am trying to unit test a WPF control and need to simulate key down presses.  I have seen a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c/1646568#1646568), however when I try to pass in a PresentationSource I keep getting a null value (from either PresentationSource.FromVisual() or PresentationSource.FromDependencyObject()) which triggers an exception.

My question is how do I get a non-null PresentationSource that I can use in unit tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out after reading this [post](http://www.wpfwiki.com/Default.aspx?Page=WPF%20Q8.2&Discuss=1&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

Basically, you need to put your control inside a Window and call Window.Show() on it.  The post mentioned an WPF bug, but I didn't encounter this in WPF 4.

After calling Window.Show(), the presentation source will no longer be null and you will be able to send keys to the control.

Comment: Calling 'InvokeShutdown' on the 'CurrentDispatcher' was the missing link in resolving the 'InvalidComObjectException' on exit. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 22):

You can extend the PresentationSource class like this:

```
public class FakePresentationSource : PresentationSource
{
    protected override CompositionTarget GetCompositionTargetCore()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override Visual RootVisual { get; set; }

    public override bool IsDisposed { get { return false; } }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var uiElement = new UIElement();

uiElement.RaiseEvent(new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, new FakePresentationSource(), 0, Key.Delete) 
{ 
    RoutedEvent = UIElement.KeyDownEvent 
});
```

Answer (score 9):

A quicker solution for unit tests is just to mock the PresentationSource object. Note that it requires an STA thread. *Sample uses Moq and nunit.*

```
[Test]
[RequiresSTA]
public void test_something()
{
  new KeyEventArgs(
    Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
    new Mock<PresentationSource>().Object,
    0,
    Key.Back);
}
```