# WPF- How to set event Up, Down, Left, Right without using the Up, Down, Left and Right Arrow Key?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button, setfocus

I am doing HCI (Human Computer Interaction) using face tracking. I am trying to control PC using face.

I have 3x3 2 dimensional grid of button. 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

Suppose, current focus on button 5. if I press up arrow then focus will be on 2, down arrow focus will be on 8 , left arrow 4 and right arrow 6.

I want to implement functionality of Up,Down,Left and Right arrow functionality without using Up,Down,Left and Right arrow key. I have already done taking left,right, up and down decision. What eventhandling, setting up tabindex and further process need to be taken?

Comment: Suppose you have a 3x3 matrix of buttons. You track a row and col value of the focus button. Up means row-- etc. When you make a change, set the focus to the appropriate button. It seems easy, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about how to raise Key board press events then i think you can use [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3w7761b%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) Class.

I assume you want to create a program that uses Face tracking to convert user movement in to UP DOWN etc Keypress events. Above class has a method Send() method that accepts an keycode and passes the Key to Active Application.

Like:

```
SendKeys.Send("{UP}");//For UP arrow key
```

As you have already created methods for shifting focus to respective Buttons in Grid you can just Send the respective key when the Event is raised.

However FaceDetection is a Research level task and you need to implement it yourself or find some good library for raising those events it.

---

There's an [**OpenCVDotNet**](http://code.google.com/p/opencvdotnet/) library that can be used to do  such thing. Its actually a .Net wrapper for [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) library. Head over to their website and see how you van use it.

---

**Update**

To generate Key press events in **WPF** you make look at this SO Answer.

[How can I programmatically generate keypress events in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c/1646568#1646568)

Comment: Oh!! its WPF didn't noticed that.. well SendKeys dosen't work in WPF.. let me see if there is an alternative..otherwise you may need to StepDown to WinForms...