# Textbox convert sent key : Alt + Enter -> Enter

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'd like to be able to modify the behaviour of the wpf textbox without the need of implementing a new class.

I want an Excel like enter / Alt+Enter behavior, when the user hits "Enter" the textbox is validated (movefocus ...), but when he hits "ALT+Enter", the textbox has to add a new line (my textbox supports multiline : AcceptsReturn is true).

I've tried (in the textbox PreviewKeyDown event):
- Raising to construct a KeyEventArgs and a TextCompositionEventArgs following this link : [How can I programmatically generate keypress events in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c)
- I've tried SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}") but it sends many new line commands

Is there a way to do this ?

Thank you

```
    private void m_MeasurementName_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = (sender as TextBox);

        if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Enter))
        {
            // 1st try
            var key = "\n\r";
            var routedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;
            tb.RaiseEvent(new TextCompositionEventArgs(InputManager.Current.PrimaryKeyboardDevice, new TextComposition(InputManager.Current, tb, key)) { RoutedEvent = routedEvent });

            // 2nd
            var key = Key.Enter;
            var routedEvent = TextCompositionManager.TextInputEvent;
            tb.RaiseEvent(new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, PresentationSource.FromVisual(tb), 0, key) { RoutedEvent = routedEvent });

            // 3rd
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");

            // 4th Strangely works but not ... you know
            MessageBox.Show("ALT+ENTER");

            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Enter))
        {
            tb.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code in textBox PreviewKeyDown routine to give us the chance to give you a better help?

Comment: Mh, can't you concatenate to current text a simple "\n" character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the user presses Alt+Enter, simply add a new line onto the existing `TextBox.Text`. If they hit just Enter, trigger an `UpdateSource` on the Text Binding

```
private void m_MeasurementName_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = (sender as TextBox);

    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Enter))
    {
        tb.Text += "\r\n";
        tb.SelectionStart = tb.Text.Length;

        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Enter))
    {
        var textBinding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(
            tb, TextBox.TextProperty);

        if (textBinding != null)
            textBinding.UpdateSource();

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

For the NewLine to work, make sure `AcceptsReturn="True"` on your `TextBox`

Comment: It works but I feel so dumb now :( Btw the caret is at the first but I've fixed it by adding tb.SelectionStart = tb.Text.Length; after tb.Text += ..., and now the carret is at the last position

Comment: @Arslan Don't worry, I'm sure everyone over-thinks problems at some point or another. Glad it works though, and I'll add your comment to my answer :)