# How to simulate Keystrokes in C#?

Tags: c#, sendkeys, keystroke

Google gives [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx) but it seems to only work for a WindowsForms class. I'm completely new to C#. What I'm trying to make is a program that monitors for an event, and then (for example), acts as if the 'H' key has been pressed. I don't really want to worry about what the active window is or anything, or sending a keystroke to an application, I just want the program to act as if I have physically pressed the 'H' button on my keyboard. The SendKeys class doesn't seem to work in a general class. Am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Comment: C# alone can't handle this. You need to get lower level than this. You can use pinvoke to call the necessary keyboard hooks. Here's an example (abandoned, I'm afraid, but the functionality to receive keyboard events is already there) -- https://github.com/eberle1080/Kaptivate

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c) includes answers referencing pretty much all of the variations I know.

Comment: Some projects can be a really bad choice when you get started on programming.  This is one of them.

Comment: I answered for the same question in another page. Please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c/12228166#12228166). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [***How to: Simulate Mouse and Keyboard Events in Code***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx):

> Windows Forms provides several options for programmatically simulating mouse and keyboard input.
>
> **Simulating Mouse Input**
> The best way to simulate mouse events is to call the `OnEventName` method that raises the mouse event you want to simulate.
>
> **Simulating Keyboard Input**
> Although you can simulate keyboard input by using the strategies discussed above for mouse input, Windows Forms also provides the `SendKeys` class for sending keystrokes to the active application.