# How to bind a hand wave on Kinect to a keypress

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I've looked around on the internet and cannot find anything, does anyone know of a way to bind a hand wave to a keypress?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked here?

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/

Comment: Already looked through there, couldn't find anything regarding keybinding :(

Comment: There should be ways to _read input_ from the Kinect device. It's up to you to raise an event related to a keypress (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to import in code user32.dll

Than you just use this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{Right}");
```

Works for me :) You need to put the line above in the part of your code where the gesture is recognized

Answer (score 1):

About SendKeys you can read this [system.windows.forms.sendkeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

Then you can check this for wave hand

```
first.Joints[JointType.HandRigh].Position.X
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a project that binds kinect gestures to keyboard events and mouse movements. It's from a prerelease Kinect SDK, so it might not be 100 % compatible with what you are using right now:

http://www.kinecteducation.com/blog/tag/binding-keys-for-kinect/