# WPF: Convert Ctrl+Enter to Enter on a TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox, keydown

I have a multiline textbox on which Ctrl+Enter triggers a specific action. Enter, obviously, creates a new line in the textbox.

Now I would like to invert the two functionalities, i.e. Ctrl+Enter should create a new line and Enter should trigger my specific action. Everything works fine, except where I need to create a new line with Ctrl-Enter.

I tried this solution:
[How can I programmatically generate keypress events in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c)
It doesn't work however, because when I raise a (Preview)Keydown/Up for the Enter key, the Ctrl key is still pressed, so I just end up simulating another Ctrl-Enter on the textbox, which has no effect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just found another way to do this, but I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question until 8 more hours...

Comment: hehe^.. I upvoted you to maybe help? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I finally simulated an "Enter" on the textbox, even when the Ctrl key is down:

```
var caretIndex = MyTextBox.CaretIndex;
MyTextBox.Text = MyTextBox.Text.Insert(caretIndex, System.Environment.NewLine);
MyTextBox.CaretIndex = caretIndex + 1;
```

Comment: For anyone following along, as a general best practice `System.Environment.NewLine` should be used instead of `\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to REALLY simulate some keypress, not just copy it's functionality, you should use [InputSimulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/), it's a great opensource library.
Simulating a Ctrl+Enter would look like:

```
InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
```