# How to delete delay on SendKeys.SendWait?

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello I want to press a button with my app. So I use SendKeys class

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{RIGHT}");
```

Problem is that I need to wait 3-4 seconds after this line code for reaction from system. How can I speed it up or how can I delete this delay ?

// update 1
I've also tried

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{RIGHT}");
SendKeys.Flush();
```

BUt id didn't help

// update 2

I want my app that works in background to press a button programaticly in the actual active state of the user. So if he is in excel i want the right arrow to move the active cell, if he is in the game i want to turn right etc. SendWait does the thing I want but with some delay that I don't want.

Second important thing that this is not a virus or worm or anything like that. First of all as you can see I'm too stupid for that and secondly I'm playing with my KInect so this is some kind of interaction beetwen user and computer. Thats why it works in background and thats why I need to send it to the active app of the user

Comment: Cause I get InvalidOperationException and comment from my VS "SendKeys cannot run inside this application because the application is not handling Windows messages.  Either change the application to handle messages, or use the SendKeys.SendWait method."

Comment: What type of application are you attempting to send the keys to?  Please include as many details as possible in your questions.

Comment: Have you selected the window? `Because there is no managed method to activate another application, you can either use this class within the current application or use native Windows methods, such as FindWindow and SetForegroundWindow, to force focus on other applications.`

Comment: Are you asking how to make the other application faster?

Comment: I've update my post. No SLaks the app works ok but I get a strange delay on SendWait method. DevinM - what do you mean ? Maybe I'm missing something trivial ? I'm looking for good example of Send method

Answer (score 1):

SendKeys is a nice little feature for Windows Form applications.  Based on your tag it appears that you're using Windows Presentation Foundation, which will not support `SendKeys.Send()`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1646568/340574

Take a look at the link above to use KeyEventArgs. I've read that you could also add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll through Visual Studio to use SendKeys, but I have not tried it myself.

Comment: could you help me with this code ? On line PresentationSource.FromVisual(target), I get The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.PresentationSource.FromVisual(System.Windows.Media.Visual)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Fixus I'm facing exactly the same problem. Did you found an alternative?

Comment: unfortunatly not. My luck that I could afford some delay