# How to create a KeyEventArgs object in WPF ( related to a SO answer )

Tags: c#, wpf

I've found this answer which look like what I need:

[How can I programmatically generate keypress events in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c/1646568#1646568)

Except for the fact I can't create an instance of `KeyEventArgs` ( I don't know how )

The code in question is:

```
 var key = Key.Insert;                    // Key to send
  var target = Keyboard.FocusedElement;    // Target element
  var routedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent; // Event to send

  target.RaiseEvent(
    new KeyEventArgs(
      Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
      PresentationSource.FromVisual(target), //<--- HERE, I can't
      0,
      key)
    { RoutedEvent=routedEvent }
  );
```

The compiler says:

```
The best overloaded method match for
'System.Windows.PresentationSource.FromDependencyObject(System.Windows.DependencyObject)'
 has some invalid arguments
```

The ide says:

Argument type `IInputElement` is not assignable to parameter type `DependencyObject`

And across StackOverflow I've found several answers directing to that answer but none of them address how to create the instance in first place.

How can I do that?

Comment: If any one is looking for a simple and fast way to simulate a keyPressed my answer on the original question could help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37029044/2363706

Answer (score 60, accepted):

phewwww

I've found it: `Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource` has to be used

```
InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(
    new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
        Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource,
        0, Key.Tab)
    {
       RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent
    }
);
```

Comment: Why don't you accept your own answer? It was pretty useful ;)

Comment: This solution does not work in a unit test project. `Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource` is null which leads to an exception.

Answer (score 18):

Similar to Bill Tarbell's answer, you can also create a dummy [System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource(v=vs.110).aspx), like so:

```
var kea = new KeyEventArgs(
    Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, 
    new HwndSource(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "", IntPtr.Zero), // dummy source
    0, 
    key);
```

Comment: Very useful! I was struggling with it for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If anyone is trying to create the KeyEventArgs for use in a **unit test** you'll find that Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource is null.. and throws an exception when you try to use it.

Mocking a PresentationSource is a workable solution (requires sta):

```
[Test]
[RequiresSTA]
public void test_something()
{
  new KeyEventArgs(
    Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
    new Mock<PresentationSource>().Object,
    0,
    Key.Back);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To **unit test** a viewmodel I had to use a combination of OscarRyz and Elijah W. Gagne answer to make this work.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void method_event_expected()
    {
        this.objectUnderTest.TestMethod(
            new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, new HwndSource(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "", IntPtr.Zero), 0, Key.Oem3)
            {
                RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent
            });

        Assert.IsTrue(...)
    }
```

Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource was null so I had to fake it with a dummy window and then I also needed the RoutedEvent to be assigned.

Answer (score -3):

```
var kea = new KeyEventArgs(
    Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
    new HwndSource(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "", IntPtr.Zero),
    0,
    Key.Enter)
    {
        RoutedEvent = UIElement.KeyUpEvent
    };
```