# Trigger a keyboard key press event without pressing the key from keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-events

How can I trigger a key press event without pressing the key from Keyboard? I tried with the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c), but I got the following exception:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Windows.PresentationSource.FromVisual(System.Windows.Media.Visual)'
>   has some invalid arguments.

Consider <kbd>Shift+A</kbd> contains 2 key press event from keyboard,how can I do it without keyboard pressing?(let, just print capital A in a textbox on a button click)

**My code**

```
var key = Key.A;                    // Key to send
var target = Keyboard.FocusedElement;    // Target element
var routedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent; // Event to send

target.RaiseEvent(new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, System.Windows.PresentationSource.FromVisual(target), 0, key) { RoutedEvent = routedEvent });
```

Comment: have you tried the sendkeys example in your link?

Comment: @RandomUs1r,Yes i tried,but a need a target to send that key.If a have 10 textboxes in a form,then what should be the criteria?I want to write A where there is current focus for which i used Keyboard.FocusedElement in above code.Do you have any idea?

Comment: I would use the focusmanager class instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.aspx .  On a higher level though, I would probably try to implement something like this in jQuery.

Comment: @RandomUs1r jQuery... in WPF?!?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send()` has done the trick for me.

For advanced instructions and the list of available codes, consult [the docs for the method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For example, to send <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> I used `SendKeys.Send("+(a)")`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast to `Visual` :

```
var key = Key.A;                    // Key to send
var target = Keyboard.FocusedElement;    // Target element
var routedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent; // Event to send

target.RaiseEvent(new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
 System.Windows.PresentationSource.FromVisual((Visual)target), 0, key) { RoutedEvent = routedEvent });
```

You could also specify that your target is a specific textbox for example :

```
var target = textBox1;    // Target element
```

What the code actually does is trigger the keydown event for a specific element. So it makes sense to have a keydown handler for it :

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: But a get a new exception while trying your above code,Value cannot be null.Parameter name: v ...

Comment: I put this code into a button click event(is this a problem?).And the full exception was that what i mentioned.

Comment: @ridoy I also have it in a button click, but I'm not using this line `var target = Keyboard.FocusedElement;` because the focused element would be the button, you need to specify the target as the name of your textbox. e.g : `var target = YourTextBox;`

Comment: I see,thanks for pointing the error.But i need to do it for any case,not for a single textbox.Assume,i have 10 textboxes in a form,then what should be the criteria?

Comment: You can set the button `Focusable="False"`. And you can use `var target = Keyboard.FocusedElement;` This way the textbox will be focused even if you click the button.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.  System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("A") has done the trick for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Easy and reliable way to simulate the keyboard event is to use the keybd_event api

You can get reference to it here

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.keybd_event

There are further articles on it here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7305/Keyboard-Events-Simulation-using-keybd_event-funct