# TreeViewItem with TextBox in WPF: type special characters

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I need to edit some hierarchical structure and I use `TreeView` with `TextBoxes`

Short example

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Items>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Level 0">
            <!-- Level 1-->
            <TextBox Margin="5"
                     BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" />
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView.Items>
</TreeView>
```

When I type in `TextBox`, `+`, `-`, letters and digits work fine, arrows work but when I press `-`, `Level 0` item collapses and when I type `*`, nothing happens

How should I handle `-` and `*` to see them in `TextBox` as expected?

Edit:

`-` works if typed as `Key.OemMinus` but not from numeric keyboard as `Key.Subtract`

`*` works if typed as `Shift`+`Key.D8` but not from numeric keyboard as `Key.Multiply`

Comment: `Key.Multiply` should work fine.  It does in my solution.

Comment: @NETscape, it doesn't work for me if I try to type `Key.Multiply` in TextBox when `Level 0` item is selected

Comment: Ahh, now I made the item selectable, selected it first, and it didn't work. Interesting!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

finally solved the problem with `Key.Subtract`

I added handler to `PreviewKeyDown` on `TextBox`

```
<TextBox Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" 
         PreviewKeyDown="TextBoxPreviewKeyDown"
/>
```

on receiving `Key.Subtract`, `KeyDown` is marked as handled and then i manually raise `TextInput` event as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1646568/1506454)  ([How can I programmatically generate keypress events in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c) )

```
private void TextBoxPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Subtract)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        var text = "-";
        var target = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
        var routedEvent = TextCompositionManager.TextInputEvent;

        target.RaiseEvent(
            new TextCompositionEventArgs
                (
                     InputManager.Current.PrimaryKeyboardDevice,
                    new TextComposition(InputManager.Current, target, text)
                )
                {
                    RoutedEvent = routedEvent
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I can suggest a keydown event for the textboxes that you have.

```
<TextBox Margin="5" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"
                     BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" />


 private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
    TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;
    if(e.Key == Key.Subtract)
    {
        txt.Text += "-";
        txt.SelectionStart = txt.Text.Length;
        txt.SelectionLength = 0;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.Multiply)
    {
        txt.Text += "*";
        txt.SelectionStart = txt.Text.Length;
        txt.SelectionLength = 0;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

It's not a good solution but it works. If you have any other "problem" keys, you can add an if to the event.

`SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` are for positioning cursor at the end of textbox. And `e.Handled = true;` does prevent the default behaviour.

Comment: thank you for suggestion, `txt.Text += "-";` is not exactly what I needed (there can be selected text to replace). I had to find another workaround