# How to make pressing a key on a keyboard is like pressing another key?

Tags: c#, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am doing something like joystick and i want each movement in it to be like pressing a certain key on a keyboard as when i move it up it is like pressing 'u' key to the computer

Comment: Did you try to search? [click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548(v=vs.110).aspx), [click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1645815/1997232)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Autohotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) for this task.

> AutoHotkey (AHK) is a free, open-source macro-creation and automation software for Windows that allows users to automate repetitive tasks. It is driven by a scripting language that was initially aimed at providing keyboard shortcuts, otherwise known as hotkeys, that over time evolved into a full-fledged scripting language.

It's very easy to achieve your goal with it.

1. Use [Joystick test script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/JoystickTest.htm) to determine the Joystick key number N
2. Create an .ahk file with following code and execute it (N replaced by the number from step 1)

   ```
   JoyN::u
   ```

That's it.

[Keyremapping](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) in AHK