# Is there a way to simulate a keypress?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working with Deepmotion Avatar in Unity 3D and it has prebuilt features like W/Up key for moving forward, S/down key for moving backward etc.

I am trying to automate the character movement in order to collect data based on the movement of the avatar. So the only approach I could think of was to simulate the <kbd>W</kbd> key press to make the character move automatically. However, I don't know how to automate the character movement in Unity 3D.

Comment: You want to simulate key presses inside of Unity or using an external script?

Comment: Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/q/1645815/7111561 but not sure if this will work for you

Comment: Did you also try to rather contact the support of the producer of that software directly? Maybe there is a simple API you can use instead ...